# resizeToAvoidBottomPadding not working, Keyboard hides textform

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

resizeToAvoidBottomPadding (true and false) function not working,when textfield is tapped, the textform remains hidden behind.

Tried also with resizeToAvoidBottomInset (true and false) and nothing seems to work.

Here's my login page code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text('Cons',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(48.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text('Tech',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(220.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                    child: Text('.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.green)),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'EMAIL',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'CONSTRASEÑA',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))),
                      obscureText: true,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 20.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Text(
                          'Reestablecer Contraseña',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.green,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                    Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      child: Material(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                        color: Colors.green,
                        elevation: 7.0,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                              'LOGIN',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Container(
                      height: 40.0,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                style: BorderStyle.solid,
                                width: 1.0),
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Center(
                              child:
                                  ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/facebook.png')),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                            Center(
                              child: Text('Log in con facebook',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat')),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
            SizedBox(height: 15.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'No tienes cuenta ?',
                  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 5.0),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/signup');
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Registro',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Id like to tap the password field and have the whole scaffold to move upwards to let the user see whats currently being typed.

Heres my flutter doctor output.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.3.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.648], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.32.3)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Wrap the first `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView` to allow scrolling.

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
       child: Column(
       ...
```

Comment: When should we wrap the Column with Expanded and when with SingleChildScrollView?

Answer (score 29):

```
Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,//deprecated
```

`resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` is deprecated after Flutter v1.1.9.

---

```
Scaffold(
    resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,//use this
```

Use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to specify if the body should resize when the keyboard appears.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use "resizeToAvoidBottomInset" to specify if the body should resize when the keyboard appears. This feature was deprecated after v1.1.9.please use "resizeToAvoidBottomInset" instead  of "resizeToAvoidBottomPadding".

Answer (score 0):

cahnge `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` to '`resizeToAvoidBottomInset`'

run in terminal

```
flutter clean
dart pub upgrade
```

add this script in index.html

```
 <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

  <script>
    // TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration.
    // See: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://[YOUR_PROJECT].firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "[YOUR_PROJECT]",
      storageBucket: "[YOUR_PROJECT].appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "...",
      appId: "1:...:web:...",
      measurementId: "G-..."
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>

  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

[reference](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/2455)