# Flutter : Scaffold not resizing after i open the keyboard

Tags: flutter, keyboard, scaffold

the keyboard is covering the TextField,
I have tried setting the `resizeToAvoideBottomInsets` to `true` but the scaffold is still not resizing and the keyboard is still covering the `TextField` .
here is the code :

```
class MessageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Chat chat;

  const MessageScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.chat,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MessageScreen> createState() => _MessageScreenState();
}

class _MessageScreenState extends State<MessageScreen> {
  final ScrollController _scrollController =
      ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 1, keepScrollOffset: true);
  late String orgId;
  late String chatId;
  late String name;
  late List<Messages> msgs =[];
  late int x = 1;
  final MessageController c = Get.put(MessageController());

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();

    orgId = widget.chat.organization_id;
    chatId = widget.chat.id.toString();
    name = widget.chat.registration["name"];
    // print("\n\n\n>>>>>>$chatId");

    context
        .read<MessageBloc>()
        .add(((GetAllMessagesEvent(org: orgId, id: chatId))));
    c.getAllMessages(chatId);
    context.read<SendMessageBloc>();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final sendMessageBloc = BlocProvider.of<SendMessageBloc>(context);
    final messageBloc = BlocProvider.of<MessageBloc>(context);
    // late Map<String , MessageModel> allMessages;
    return BlocListener<MessageBloc,MessageState>(
        listener: (context, state){
          if(state is MessageLoadedState){
            setState(() {
              // print(state.messages);
              // print(state.messages);
              c.addMessage=state.messages;
              // print(c.messagez.length);
            });
          }
        },
        child:Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         toolbarHeight: 60,
         title:
         Text(name, style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
         leading: Container(
             margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
             alignment: Alignment.center,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                 borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                 color: Colors.white),
             child: Text(widget.chat.registration['company_name'],
                 style: const TextStyle(
                     color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15))),
       ),
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
       // extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
       body: Column(
         children: [
           Expanded(
             child: Stack(
               children: [
                 Obx(()=>ListView.builder(

                   itemCount: c.messagez!.length,
                   reverse: true,
                   itemBuilder: (context, index)=> Column(
                       children: List.generate(growable: true,
                                    c.messagez[index].messages!.length,
                                    (index2) => Obx(()=>MessageWidget(msg:c.messagez![index]
                                        .messages![index2])),
                              ).reversed.toList())),),


  
               ],
             ),
           ),
           Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
             child: TextField(
               decoration:
               InputDecoration(filled: true, fillColor: Colors.red),
             ),
           )
         ],
       )
```

I have tried setting the `resizeToAvoideBottomInsets` to `true` but the scaffold is still not resizing and the keyboard is covering the `TextField` .

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproducible example of code? It will be helpful to let us understand your problem.

Comment: this is the whole page , I'm afraid I'm not allowed to post more than that on the internet

Comment: Yeah! Thats the point. Could you create a main file with a simple example that does have the same problem of this one so you copy/paste and run the example?

Comment: No I can't .. I'm not allowed to by the person that owns the code

Comment: That's ok! I'm just telling to you create a new, simple, small and "sharable" with no sensitive file so We can try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Scaffold` with `SingleChildScrollView`. For more detail see below question link.

[ResizeToAvoidBottomInset not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369388/resizetoavoidbottompadding-not-working-keyboard-hides-textform)